# Exception has occurred: TypeError Expected cv::UMat for argument 'src' when passing MoviePy colourClip into OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, moviepy

When I pass a MoviePy colour Clip into OpenCV I get the following error message

Exception has occurred: TypeError
Expected cv::UMat for argument 'src'

```
import moviepy.editor as mped
import moviepy as mpie
import numpy as np
import sys
import cv2

print('MoviePy version', mpie.__version__) # = version 1.0.2
print("Python Version", sys.version) # = version 3.7.3

colour_clip = mped.ColorClip(size=[50, 75], color=np.array([125, 190, 50]).astype(np.uint8), duration=3)
bgr_col_clip = cv2.cvtColor(colour_clip, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
```

I was wondering if you could help me understand what it is about the colorClip that OpenCV doesn't agree with ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons for this error.

1. image is null
2. image is corrupted

**Suggestion**
`print(image)` or dump of `cv2.utils.dumpInputArray(image)` may help you.

---- add ---
you are getting all video as object and it canot be converted into np array.
you net to grab the frame, ex:

```
import moviepy.editor as mpe
video = mpe.VideoFileClip('some_video.mp4')
while True:
    np_frame = video.get_frame()
```

Comment: print(colour_clip) will produce the object reference
<moviepy.video.VideoClip.ColorClip object at 0x0000020A7D5CFA58>

cv2.utils.dumpInputArray(colour_clip) will give the same error message
Exception has occurred: TypeError Expected cv::UMat for argument 'src'